# Removing unwanted space which automatically is entered before numeric data when written to a text file

Tags: vb.net

I have a program which writes data into a text file. I have found that when the data is written to the text file any numeric data has a space before it, whereas the data that is type string has no space before. I would like to know how to remove this unwanted space if possible. The full code and example of an output is below:

**Code:**

```
Sub Main()
    Dim file As String = "c:\users\finne\desktop\datafile.txt"
    Dim inputCode As Integer
    Dim inputDescription As String
    Dim inputPrice As Single

    FileOpen(1, file, OpenMode.Output)

    Console.Write("Enter the product code: ")
    inputCode = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.Write("Enter the product description: ")
    inputDescription = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.Write("Enter the product price: £")
    inputPrice = Console.ReadLine()

    PrintLine(1, inputCode)
    PrintLine(1, inputDescription)
    PrintLine(1, inputPrice)
    PrintLine(1, " ")

    FileClose(1)
    Console.WriteLine("The data has been entered successfully.")
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
 243434 
Toy Car
 10.5
```

Comment: Try to type a negative value for any of your "numbers"

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the code file.  `Console.ReadLine()` never returns an integer.  Also, the IDE (still) should be warning you that those legacy `FileOpen` and `PrintLine()` methods are antiquated and have much better VB replacements (with even better ones in .NET)

Comment: Do like @Plutonix wrote or trim(inputCode) and trim(inputPrice) before writeline.

Comment: @statosdotcom Numbers don't have whitespace to trim.

Comment: ops... but do readline() don't read them as strings?

Comment: Visual Studio isn't giving me any warnings, weird. I'll give that a try now @Plutonix.

Comment: When the value is negative there is no space. That kinda explains that problem @Steve

Comment: @statosdotcom Because Option Strict is off, they are getting inferred/converted to the declared type. One of the many reasons you should never have it off as it hides a lot of stuff and does a lot of black magic you won't find until it's usually too late. If it wasn't for them trying to be backwards compatible or try to convert legacy VB code, they should have completely gotten rid of that option and always forced it to be on.

Comment: So we agreed that, at the case in focus, readline() read Number as Strings. And I agree with you too, "Numbers don't have whitespace to trim", but I was suggesting OP to trim a String, NaN. Thanks.

Comment: The old PrintLine function (still available for VB6 compatibility) writes all numbers keeping a front space for sign. In case of positive value the space is leaved as is, in case of negative numbers you see the - in front to your number. Instead if you use the current StreamWriter class you will have your expected output. Use the current Framework methods and discard the old VB6 ones

Comment: @statosdotcom It has nothing to do with `ReadLine()`. Think of it as allowing `Dim foo As Integer = "123"`

Comment: That makes sense, great explanation too. I'll take that on-board, thanks @Steve.

Comment: @TyCobb - or at least turned `Option Strict on` by default.  I can see some justification for leaving it available for old code that may rely heavily on said black magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old PrintLine function (still available for VB6 compatibility) writes all numbers keeping a front space for sign. In case of positive value the space is leaved as is, in case of negative numbers you see the - in front to your number. Instead if you use the current StreamWriter class you will have your expected output. Use the current Framework methods and discard the old VB6 ones

```
Using sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(file)
   sw.WriteLine(inputCode)
   sw.WriteLine(inputDescription)
   sw.WriteLine(inputPrice)
End Using
```

Also, as everyone is telling you, go to your project properties and switch the Option Strict to the ON setting. This will force your code to correctly convert your strings to the appropriate datatype for numbers

For example

```
Console.Write("Enter the product code: ")
Dim userInput as String = Console.ReadLine()
If Not Int32.TryParse(userInput, inputCode) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Please type an integer number")
    Application.Exit()
End If
```